# Rails Page Specific Maintenance Mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, rack

I have a rails 4.1 application that is in production. There have been one or two instances recently where it would have been beneficial to have one page on maintenance mode while the rest of the site is live. I would like to toggle maintenance page on foobar.com/sign_in by changing the value of an environmental variable or by running a rake task.

I'm open to either using a gem or writing my own tool to handle this. How are other people solving this problem?

Answer (score 3):

You can use **turnout** gem for this:

https://rubygems.org/gems/turnout